# when do we have polynomial local minimum = to global minimum

Tags: polynomials, optimization

When does a multivariate polynimial has only one stationary point so that local minimum is global minimum?

Comment: This happens when the polynomial is convex, see [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28983/characterizing-convex-polynomials) question for information on how to decide whether a polynomial is convex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is very difficult question, and there is no answer in general.

You can only come up with some sufficient conditions, such as convexity, as suggested by @mrp in comments. However, this is certainly not necessary --- take for instance $ x^4 + 4x^3 + x$.